# How to find a value from array object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a array object I want to return `and` if it will find in this array otherwise it will return `or` I want to just return value not key.

Currently it return Object & I need only value.

```js
const arrObj = [
    {
        "relation_type": "undefined"
    },
    {
        "relation_type": "or"
    },
    {
        "relation_type": "and"
    },
    {
        "relation_type": "or"
    },
    {
        "relation_type": "or"
    }
]


let obj = arrObj.find((o) => {
      if (o.relation_type === "and") {
        return true;
      }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: could you write what you expect exactlly?

Comment: If I understand that correctly you want something like `const result = arrObj.some(o => o.relation_type === 'and') ? 'and' : 'or'`.

Comment: Thanks you @Felix Kling it working fine as I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like that :

`let obj = arrObj.find(o => o.relation_type === "and") ? "and" : "or"`

Comment: *"One way to achieve this would be to return o.relation_type instead of true inside your obj variable."* I assume you are referring to the call to `.find` but no, that's not how `.find` works. It doesn't return the value returned from the callback.

Comment: `arrObj.find(o => o.relation_type === "and").relation_type` would always return `"and"` or throw an error.

Comment: @rmfy what about if there is "and" not available in array?

Comment: @FelixKling you're right, updated my OP !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can simply use destruction:

```
let {relation_type} = arrObj.find((o) => {
  if (o.relation_type === "and") {
    return true;
  }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .map method and loop over and access the relation type as a property here is a working example

```js
const arrObj = [
    {
        "relationtype": "undefined"
    },
    {
        "relationtype": "or"
    },
    {
        "relationtype": "and"
    },
    {
        "relationtype": "or"
    },
    {
        "relationtype": "or"
    }
]

{arrObj.map((object,index)=> 
console.log(object.relationtype)
    )}
```

[.map() MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)