# React - NextJS Select - How to loop through object with values in fetch and return only values that exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am using the NHL api to try to grab players stats for a given season. I have a utility function with these season values :

```
export const seasonOptions = [
  { value: "19861987", label: "1986/1987" },
  { value: "19871988", label: "1987/1988" },
  { value: "19881989", label: "1988/1989" },
  { value: "19891990", label: "1989/1990" },
  { value: "19901991", label: "1990/1991" },
  { value: "19911992", label: "1991/1992" },
  { value: "19921993", label: "1992/1993" },
  { value: "19931994", label: "1993/1994" },
  { value: "19941995", label: "1994/1995" },
  { value: "19951996", label: "1995/1996" },
];
```

... and so on. In my component I have this state to setSelect on what was selected:

```
 const [select, setSelect] = useState(seasonOptions[seasonOptions.length - 1]);
 

  const handler = (selected) => {
 
      setSelect((select) => select);
      handlePlayerStats(
        `https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${props.playerId}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=${selected.value}`
      );
    }
  };


<Select
        id="select"
        instanceId={"select"}
        options={seasonOptions}
        placeholder={select.label}
        autoFocus
        value={select.value}
        onChange={handler}
      />
```

Which calls this custom hook:

```
const handlePlayerStats = async (url) => {
    try {
      const req = await fetch(url).then((response) => response.json());
      console.log(req);
      if (req.messageNumber) {
        setFetchedData([]);
      } else if (req.stats[0].splits.length > 0) {
        setFetchedData(req);
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I'm not really sure how to go about looping through all the seasonOptions dynamically and filtering out each season where req.stats[0].splits.length === 0?

Here is the codesandbox link for anyone curious: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kapitsa-c97rzy?file=/components/PlayerStats.js:357-855

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right. You want to basically delete every object from req.stats that has the splits smaller than 0? And also splits is what, an array, or a string ? Because length smaller than 0 is illogical.

Comment: Can you try to develop a code sandbox i think i can help you with this one.! Great Job so far checkout my example of how to access the values using ````.map()``` method for the first part of your question

Comment: @AlexMatei My bad I meant to type req.stats[0].splits.length ===0. For example: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20052006 Here splits is populated but if you change the season to https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20042005  Splits is now an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Answer The first parst of your question you can map over this Array of Objects with this method for example using the `.map` method

[React Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-question-for-seasons-mapping-andfiltering-ri8liz?file=/src/App.js)

[MDN-.map() method JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
export const seasonOptions = [
  { value: 8471214, label: "198601987" },
  { value: 8471215, label: "198701988" },
  { value: 8471216, label: "198801989" },
  { value: 8471217, label: "198901990" },
  { value: 8471218, label: "199001991" },
  { value: 8471219, label: "199101992" },
  { value: 8471220, label: "199201993" },
  { value: 8471221, label: "199301994" },
  { value: 8471222, label: "199401995" },
  { value: 8471223, label: "199501996" },
];
    
//MAKE SURE TO MAP OVER THE <option></option> tag not the <Select/> 
//CHECK CODE SANDBOX FOR EXAMPLE IN PURE HTML5 AND REACT 
      {seasonOptions.map((option,index)=>
        <Select
        key={index}
        id="select"
        instanceId={"select"}
        options={option?.value}
        placeholder={option?.label}
        autoFocus
        value={select.value}
        onChange={handler}
      />
        
        )}
```

Check Out my Answer Here or for other examples here how to map over an array and access it values this method is just 1 of many .

[How to find a value from array object in JavaScript? Stack Over Flow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950039/how-to-find-a-value-from-array-object-in-javascript/73950218#73950218)

For the Second Part Of the Question you can use the [new SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapping-filtering-values-from-api-react-app-nhl-example-ri8liz?file=/src/App.js)

- Steps

1. Change the `value` property here from a `string` to  a `number` by removing the quotation marks `export const seasonOptions = [{value: 8471214, label: "198601987"},]`
2. Assign a `useState` hook to handle the active filtered item
   `const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState([]);`

3.Assign an arrow function to handle Filtering the Seasons
using the `setTimeOut()` method [setTimeout()-MDN-DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)  Where `500` is the time the function is executed for that time and

```
const handleSeasonsFilter = (item) => {
    setActiveFilter(item);

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (!item) {
        setFilterSeasons(item);
      } else {
        setFilterSeasons(
          seasonOptions.filter((season) =>
            seasonOptions?.includes(season?.label)
          )
        );
      }
    }, 500);
  };
```

4. Pass that to url that searches the API `` url = `https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${activeFilter}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=200402005 `` Like in `Line 65`  in The Sand Box
5. Display Them using `useEffect()` hook also add in the values in the dependency array or leave it empty to avoid infinite loops.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //debug data
    console.log(stringDataDisplay);
    setActiveFilter(activeFilter);
    //DEBUG IF VALUE IF PASSED
    //setDatasearched(activeFilter);
  }, [
    /**EMPTY DEPENDENCY ARRAY TO AVOID INFINITE LOOPS */
    stringDataDisplay,
    activeFilter
  ]);
```

in My Example i Displayed Them using another `useState` Hook and State action
`const [datasearched, setDatasearched] = useState([])`

& Finally Just Assigned a new `const stringDataDisplay = JSON.stringify([datasearched]);`
To Stringify the `[datasearched]` Array Here.

***Note***
Make sure to pass the `handleSeasonsFilter` to `OnClick` as an empty arrow function and pass the `option.value` property as a String so the API Accepts the request.

Hope this helps with your Example and  Ill try to Check the code sandbox also with your method.

Bear in Mind i still i am developing this and i understand you want the values of the seasons to be shown when no player id is selected Am i correct?

Comment: Thank you! The thing is I am looking to loop through this end point: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20052006 using season options to replace '20052006' then returning each result filtering out seasons where the splits array would be empty. I haven't used code sandbox before. Would I just import the whole code base?

Comment: So basically you want to filter out players by seasons ? and display that value using the ```value: ``` prop mentioned in the seasonsOptions Array of Objects am i correct ? for the code sandbox question You would replicate it as much as you can with the parts you need for the question to minimize efforts , a swell for the steps for the sandbox 1 . sign up for codesandbox.io 2. select create from the navigation bar on the right  3. select start from a template and choose React 4. On the left tab you will find a dependencies installer , make sure to match those from your ```package.json``` file!

Comment: and display the results according to the people ```https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/${props.playerId}/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=${selected.value}``` player id and selected value as you mentioned here?

Comment: Yeah so I'm looking into two options. First, I could go the select route and filter out the particular season value from seasonOptions if the splits array is empty like here: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20042005 . The other way could be to loop through all the season options and filter out the seasons which splits is empty, then putting all the responses into a separate array and displaying each season in a table. I'm looking into creating a sandbox with the relevant code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kapitsa-c97rzy?file=/components/PlayerStats.js:357-855  So for this example, this player only played seasons from 2005 onward. How would I go about removing the seasons from options prior to 20052006 which are null? This is only one example since in the full app, ID's are dynamic so players could have null values in x number of seasons.

Comment: thank you for the sandbox , just another tip you cant search the api with values ```2005/2006/``` for example you can use ```200502006``` to pass the value to api to ```GET``` The results , and when you display them to the end user just use ```.replace("0","|")``` method check my sandbox in ```line 91``` https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/8471214/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=200402005 this url works and gets Data from the api however if we use ```2004/2005``` would give you an error, and ill try to change your sandbox if i am able to reach the end result you want.

Comment: No problem at all mate , always glad to help !